# curl works, but won't execute in BASH script

Tags: bash, curl

The following curl command works from the command line.  I get a valid response from the server.

```
curl -X POST https://somebaseurl/api/v1/auth/login -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"email": "foo@bar,com", "password": "foo"}'
```

However I am trying to write a BASH script like this

```
baseUrl=https://somebaseurl
contentTypeJson="\"Content-Type:application/json\""
credentials="'{\"email\": \"foo@bar.com",\"password\": \"foo\"}'"
login="curl -X POST $baseUrl/api/v1/auth/login -H $contentTypeJson -d $credentials"
 echo ${login}

response=`${login}`
echo ${response}
```

I get a bad request response from the server.  However if I copy the echoed curl command directly into my terminal it works.  What am I doing wrong?

edit:

As requested I get 
   Bad Request For request 'POST api/v1/auth/login' [Expected application/json]

Comment: "i get a bad request response"  what's the response you're getting? please edit your question to include the error

Comment: @sircapsalot done, thanks

Comment: in "login", add the `-v` option to the curl command to enable verbose output.  perhaps your command isn't interpolating as expected

Comment: You shouldn't put straight quotes inside double quotes and then try to use that as a means of quoting an argument like that.  Use \"$credentials\" and remove the single quote in the assignment statement.  Same goes for the content type.  (Whether that fix solves the problem or not, I couldn't guess, but it made the code confusing.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bash` and `cURL` can be quite particular how quotes are used within a script. If the escaping gets thrown off then everything else can easily fail. Running the script through shellcheck.net is often very helpful in identifying such issues. Below is a revised version of the script after fixing based upon the suggestions:

```
#!/bin/bash

baseUrl="https://somebaseurl/api/v1/auth/login"
contentTypeJson="Content-Type:application/json"
credentials="{\"email\": \"foo@bar.com\", \"password\": \"foo\"}"
login="$(curl -X POST "$baseUrl" -H "$contentTypeJson" -d "$credentials")"
echo "${login}"

response="${login}"
echo "${response}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this got it!

Answer (score 4):

Executing with backticks interprets the command only as a sequence of words, and doesn't treat quotes specially.  To have the shell interpret quotes as if they were interactively typed, use `eval ${login}` instead.

As an aside, bash has a `-x` option which will show you commands as they are being executed (run your script with `bash -x script.sh` instead of `bash script.sh` or `./script.sh`).  This will show you the commands correctly quoted, and is more helpful than printing them out using echo.